# Disqus count not refreshing immediately

Tags: count, synchronization, refresh, disqus

I registered to Disqus 2 days ago, and I put the script on my website (**not a CMS**). Basically, it's working, comments are displayed and it's pretty easy.

BUT, the count system is totally screwed up. I get an unique identifier for each post (slug-id):

```js
var disqus_config = function () {
             //this.page.url = '/<?= $datas['slug'].'-'.$datas['id']; ?>/'; // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
             this.page.identifier = '<?= $datas['slug'].'-'.$datas['id']; ?>'; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
             };

            (function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
                var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');

                s.src = '//my-shortname.disqus.com/embed.js'; // It's the real one, i juste modified it for the post

                s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
                (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
            })();
```

The count.js script is right before the `</body>` tag

And the code for the count is :

```html
<a href="/<?= $datas['slug'].'-'.$datas['id']; ?>/#disqus_thread" 
   data-disqus-identifier="<?= $datas['slug'].'-'.$datas['id']; ?>">
</a>
```

It's working yes, but I need few minutes/hours before refresh. Look at the screenshot, I posted a comment, and the count hasn't been refreshed even if I clear my cache etc. I have to wait some minutes/hours and it'll be refreshed automatically.

[Screenshot from my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYF6t.png)

Why? How to fix it?

Comment: When asking on a separate place (like Disqus), please add the link to the related discussion.